# Automatically read/write to a user's subtree in Firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to set up firebase so that when a logged-in user is using a web application that reads and writes to the database, the database path doesn't always have to include "users/:userid/" (for example) at the beginning? That is, can the read/write automatically be done to the user's subtree?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set a default path for a specific client.

But given that you have to create each reference explicitly, you can easily fix this by deriving all references from a common root.

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref("/users/"+currentUser.uid);
rootRef.on(...
```